# TwitVid crash after successful video upload in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, twitter

Everything worked fine until I uploaded video to TwitVid using iOS 5 SDK. Video would successfully get uploaded. But as soon as it is uploaded, the application crashes saying

```
   -[TwitVidRequestStream release]: message sent to deallocated instance.
```

I tried using the latest libTwitVid.a and TwitVid.h files but in vain. How can I fix this? Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `TwitVidRequestStream` object is already released some where, and you are releasing it once again.

Answer (score 0):

A newer version of TwitVid SDK is available. You should use it instead.